# Copy a list of objects from one list to another based on id

Tags: c#, list, foreach, lambda

Basically I have two lists of objects. I need to do something like update first list from second list based on the id property that matches between the lists. How can I achieve this without using `foreach` loop.

```
public class Test1
{
    int Id;
    List<Test2> Test2Values;
}

public class Test2
{
    int Test1Id;
    string valueString;
}

public class Main
{
    public void Test()
    {
        List<Test1> testList1 = GetTest1();
        List<Test2> testList2 = GetTest2();

        foreach(Test1 t in testList1)
            t.Test2Values = testList2.Where(tl => tl.Test1Id == t.Id).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is the right way to iterate over an existing list. You could use `for` or `List<T>.ForEach`, but I'd call both those options less elegant. If you're looking for nice LINQ one-liner, I don't think it exists.

Comment: If you have a list of `Id` values and you want to *create* `Test1` instances with the appropriate `Test2` instances associated with them, then you *can* do it nicely with LINQ.

Comment: yes, this I know, but my goal is to populate existing testList1 with matching values from testList2 set.

Comment: nothing. I'm looking to see if there is any 'bulk' operation I can do. For example, there are joins you can do between lists when you are doing selects. They are much faster than regular foreach. Looking for something similar if it exists.

Comment: you can use testList2.ToDictionary() with Id as key & Test2Values as Value, this way the "where" will get optimize since you need not to go through the whole list to find instead use dictionary[Id] to get the object in one go. Will add an answer.

Comment: Yes, GroupBy / ToDictionary is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick. First build a dictionary out of `testList2`. Key it by `Test1Id`. Then select each item from `testList1`. Check if it's id is in the dictionary. If so replace the list with new values else keep the old value.

```
var dict = testList2
            .GroupBy(t2 => t2.Test1Id)
            .ToDictionary(
                gr => gr.Key, 
                gr => gr.ToList());

testList1
    .Select(t1 => 
    { 
        t1.Test2Values = dict.ContainsKey(t1.Id) ? dict[t1.Id] : t1.Test2Values;
        return t1;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Modifying the list in a `Select`.. yuck. There's nothing wrong with `foreach`, you've solved the performance issue with the dictionary. I believe it also won't actually do anything until you put a `ToList()` on the end, thanks to lazy execution.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I fixed the select. As to using `Select`, the `foreach` version is already in the question. And then the question was to get a solution without `foreach`. Just providing what I was asked for...

Answer (score 0):

get common items between two lists by using below code and then processed the next:

```
 var result = testList1.Where(p => testList2.Any(p2 => p2.Id == p.Id));
```